# How to sort order of targets when using UIControl (specifically UIButton)?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit, uibutton, uicontrol

In my app I have multiple `UIButtons` for which I add targets.

It turns out that the most recently added target is preformed first and then the remaining targets.

For example, take this code:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(someAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(someOtherAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

If I would touch up inside `button`, `someOtherAction:` would be called before `someAction`.

That's not what I want. I want to sort the targets so that I can have a touch up inside of that button first called `someAction:`ability and then other action `someOtherAction:`

I'm not sure where to begin, should I subclass and override something in `UIButton` or rather dig inside `UIControl`?

Thanks for the help!

-David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest (albeit hacky) way to do this would be to make a copy of all the action selectors, remove them from the target then re-add all of them except the one you want to have happen first.

However, your requirements are likely a side-effect of a poor design decision since this isn't behavior that should be necessary.

What is your end goal of having something happen first?

Why can't you combine both actions in one that executes the selectors in the correct order?

Comment: Thanks for idea Ben. The reason I'm doing this is quite simple: I have a UIView subclass for which I add buttons into. I only want one button to be selected at one time in the view. As a result, when I create the buttons I add a action that loops through all the buttons and "deselects them". The reason I need another selector is because my view controller adds the actual event vs my subclass. This is where I I run into the problem where the buttons action is occurring before the deselection. Do you have a idea of better design for this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't both actions happen so quickly that they appear to be simultaneous (adding the button and deselection)?

Comment: You could also keep a reference to the currently selected button to avoid looping, looking for a selected one.

Comment: Ben thanks for the idea. I don't understand completely how keeping a reference to the selected button would help (other than avoid looping) as I want to keep the unselection logic separate from the view controller (which sets the actual action). The actions also don't happen fast enough, because what happens is the view controller logic kicks in and selects the button and the UI changes for the button. Then the deselection is called and the UI changes back and by the end of day no button gets selected. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could provide an intermediary, or proxy, object that always receives the button's action, and then forwards the appropriate one from an array it contains to the ultimate destination.

One possible way of doing this would be to override the proxy object's -forwardInvocation: and -methodSignatureForSelector: methods.  See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/ForwardInvocation/Introduction/Intro.html