# UIButton with multiple target actions for same event

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

Can I add multiple target actions on a UIButton for the same event like below?

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(xxx) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button addTarget:object action:@selector(yyy) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

I made a quick app to test it out and it carries out both the actions on button press.

I want to know if it's good practice to do so, and also will the order of execution always remain the same?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I did find this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828740/how-to-sort-order-of-targets-when-using-uicontrol-specifically-uibutton) which states it's called in reverse order of addition, i.e., the most recently added target is called first. But it's not confirmed

Comment: Whether it's "a good practice to do so" is largely opinion based. The documentation makes no claims about the order so I wouldn't count on the order. In fact, I would assume the order of execution is random.

Comment: If order is important, use a single action handler and in that handler execute the tasks in the desired order.

Comment: @bsod that's a neat solution and I already thought of it, but how would I pass the target (other than `self`) and selector to the action handler?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it is possible to add multiple actions to a button.

personally i would prefer a Delegate to subscribe to the button.
Let the `object` you want to add as `target` subscribe on the delegate's method so it can receive events when you press the button.

or

A single action that forwards the event to other methods to be fully in control

A simple test in swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

      let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 300, height: 30))
      button.backgroundColor = .orange
      button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(action1), for: .touchUpInside)
      button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(action2), for: .touchUpInside)
      button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(actionHandler), for: .touchUpInside)
      self.view.addSubview(button)
  }

  @objc func actionHandler(_ sender: UIButton){
      print("actionHandler")
      action1(sender)
      action2(sender)
  }

  @objc func action1(_ sender: UIButton) {
      print("action1")
  }

  @objc func action2(_ sender: UIButton) {
      print("action2 \n")
  }
}
```

Output after one click:

```
action1
action2 

actionHandler
action1
action2
```

> Can you confirm on the order of execution when normally adding the actions

Yes it is executed in the order you set the targets.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am able to add multiple actions to a button for the same event. I am more inclined towards knowing the order of invocation and whether it's a good practice.

Comment: You should definitely look at using a delegate. i've updated the answer

Comment: thanks for updating. Can you confirm on the order of execution when normally adding the actions?

Comment: Yes it is executed in the order you set the targets. Updated the answer again.