# I can't figure out UIButton with Three States (Start, Stop, and reset)

Tags: swift, uibutton

I'm teaching myself how to write Swift code and I know it's not pretty but I'm looking more to get it working first. I know what I NEED but I can't figure it out. I have a button with one action and when you tap it I need it to change color, title and function. I have the color and the title changing but changing the function is hard. It seems I need to pass a new function in to the "startTapped" function inside the timer but I can't figure out a good way to do it. It might have something to do with lifecycle of loadView()

`timerView.actionButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(startTapped), for: .touchUpInside)`

here's the full Code snippet:

````
        view = timerView
        timerView.installContraints()
        timerView.actionButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(startTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func startTapped() {
        print("button pressed")
        activeTimer?.invalidate()

        let startDate = Date()
        activeTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true, block: { _ in
            let currentDate = Date()
            let duration = currentDate.timeIntervalSince(startDate)

            func formatDuration(DoubleDuration: (Double) -> String) {
                // make number formatter function to format the TimeInterval Double into a String??
            }

            self.timerView.timerLabel.text = "\(duration)"
        })
        timerView.actionButton.setTitle("STOP", for: .normal)
        timerView.actionButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        timerView.actionButton.backgroundColor = .red
    }

    func stopTapped() {
        print("stop tapped")
        activeTimer?.invalidate()
    }

    func resetTapped() {
        print("something")
    } ```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UIButton with multiple target actions for same event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56244140/uibutton-with-multiple-target-actions-for-same-event)

Comment: What do you mean by "changing function"? :)

Comment: You need to write a little state machine. After that it's trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to perform the actions always in the order start/stop/reset add an index variable

```
var index = 0
```

Then add a new function which calls the other functions depending on `index` and then increments the index

```
@objc func buttonTapped(_ sender : UIButton) {
     if index == 0 {
        startTapped()
     } else if index == 1 {
        stopTapped()
     } else {
        resetTapped()
     }
     index = (index + 1) % 3
}
```

and use this function as button action

```
timerView.actionButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Comment: Thank you so much this was it! Thank you so much.